# Don't remove edit link for question with pending edit on mobile

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, mobile-web

Since there's no post preview on mobile, if I make a mistake when suggesting an edit for a post, I look like an idiot and waste OP and reviewers' time with a substandard change.

<s>Canceling a suggested edit would be good. Being able to edit the suggested edit would be great.</s>

The functionality is there, but when an edit is pending, the edit link is removed on the mobile SO theme.

Comment: Edit the post you submitted the edit on. It'll be merged as a part of the edit. If you undo all changes (pro tip: pop up the revision history, copy-paste the source into the editor), it (should) retract the edit

Comment: There is no edit link or edit history before the edit is approved. Just the "Thanks for your edit!
This edit will be visible only to you until it is peer reviewed." message

Comment: `https://stackoverflow.com/posts/<id>/revisions` contains the revision history, regardless of whether the post has been edited or not

Comment: Just found an edit link appears (but not edit history) on the desktop theme. This is a mobile theme issue only.

Comment: Just switch over to the responsive theme. I have a feeling mobile web will be discontinued anyway.